How to solve "Date format picture ends before converting entire input string Error"
I wrote the below query in a procedure to retrieve the records which are less than sysdate. But getting "date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error.
select code 
from custom_codes 
where to_date(TO_CHAR(end_date,'DD-MON-YY')||' '||end_time)<sysdate;

Here, end_date has 02-JUL-24 00:00:00 and end_time has 23:00:00.

What is the data type of the end_date and end_time columns?

END_DATE           DATE,
END_TIME           VARCHAR2(8)

The error you are getting is because to_date can't decypher what you are feeding it. You can specify the format for to_date: to_date(x, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')

@VvdL In Oracle, a DATE always has a time component.

based on the end time, I need to do certain operations.. if end time is less than sys time then I need to close the order.

@VvdL to_date(x, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS) this works for me. Thanks

Rather than converting everything to strings, you can convert the time to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND and add that to the TRUNCATEd end_date:
SELECT code 
FROM   custom_codes 
WHERE  TRUNC(end_date) + TO_DSINTERVAL('0 '||end_time) < sysdate;

Note: you could also store the end_time column as an INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) data type rather than using VARCHAR2(8) then you will never store invalid times and can just add the value to the date.
Note 2: A DATE in Oracle always has a time component so unless there is a business reason to store end_date and end_time separately then you could just store end_date and include the time component rather than setting it to midnight. If you wanted the start of the day then use TRUNC.
Alternatively, ensure that you use a format model in TO_DATE as well as TO_CHAR:
SELECT code 
FROM   custom_codes 
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' '||end_time,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) < SYSDATE;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE custom_codes (code, end_date, end_time) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE-1), '23:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE), TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE), '23:59:59' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



CODE




1


2



fiddle

Will try this :)
